# Yii2: How to manually load jQuery UI?

Tags: php, jquery-ui, yii2

I've installed https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-jui but how do I manualy load the Javascript library **without using server-side code for making a widget**?

In my case I just need the `sortable()` function to be available for use on some existing code I have. I only want to have it on a specific page, not all pages. So I can't just add it to `AppAsset.php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a check in your layout view or in controller to add a checking of current page:

```
    if(Yii::$app->controller->id == 'foo' && Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'bar')
    {
        // for inside controller check
        $this->registerJs("your_js_file_path");
    }

    ... html here ...
    <?
    if(Yii::$app->controller->id == 'foo' && Yii::$app->controller->action->id == 'bar')
    {?>
        <!-- for inside controller check    -->
        <script src=""></script>
    <?}?>
    ... html here ...
```